# Functional programming with OCAML

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm new to functional programming and I'm trying to implement a basic algorithm using OCAML for course that I'm following currently.

I'm trying to implement the following algorithm :

Entries : 

- E : a non-empty set of integers

- s : an integer

- d : a positive float different of 0

Output :

- T : a set of integers included into E

m <- min(E)

T <- {m}

FOR EACH e ∈ sort_ascending(E \ {m}) DO

        IF e > (1+d)m AND e <= s THEN

              T <- T U {e}

              m <- e

RETURN T

```
let f = fun (l: int list) (s: int) (d: float) ->
      List.fold_left (fun acc x -> if ... then (list_union acc [x]) else acc) 
   [(list_min l)] (list_sort_ascending l) ;;
```

So far, this is what I have, but I don't know how to handle the modification of the "m" variable mentioned in the algorithm... So I need help to understand what is the best way to implement the algorithm, maybe I'm not gone in the right direction.

Thanks by advance to anyone who will take time to help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `list_min` is defined you should think the problem methodically. Let's say you represent a set with a list. Your function takes this set and some arguments and returns a subset of the original set, given the elements meet certain conditions.

Now, when I read this for the first time, `List.filter` automatically came to my mind.

```
List.filter : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

But you wanted to modify the `m` so this wouldn't be useful. It's important to know when you can use library functions and when you really need to create your own functions from scratch. You could clearly use `filter` while handling `m` as a reference but it wouldn't be the functional way.

First let's focus on your predicate:

```
fun s d m e -> (float e) > (1. +. d)*.(float m) && (e <= s)
```

Note that `+.` and `*.` are the plus and product functions for floats, and `float` is a function that casts an int to float.

Let's say the function `predicate` is that predicate I just mentioned.

Now, this is also a matter of opinion. In my experience I wouldn't use `fold_left` just because it's just complicated and not necessary.

So let's begin with my idea of the code:

```
let m = list_min l;;
```

So this is the initial `m`

Then I will define an auxiliary function that reads the `m` as an argument, with `l` as your original set, and `s`, `d` and `m` the variables you used in your original imperative code.

```
let rec f' l s d m =
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | x :: xs -> if (predicate s d m x) then begin
                 x :: (f' xs s d x)
               end
               else
                 f' xs s d m in
f' l s d m
```

Then for each element of your set, you check if it satisfies the predicate, and if it does, you call the function again but you replace the value of `m` with `x`.

Finally you could just call `f'` from a function `f`:

```
let f (l: int list) (s: int) (d: float) =
  let m = list_min l in
  f' l s d m
```

Be careful when creating a function like your `list_min`, what would happen if the list was empty? Normally you would use the `Option` type to handle those cases but you assumed you're dealing with a non-empty set so that's great.

When doing functional programming it's important to think functional. Pattern matching is super recommended, while pointers/references should be minimal. I hope this is useful. Contact me if you any other doubt or recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I agree with you about the fol_left usage, I think that I wanted to use it absolutely and I didn't see that it'll be just a pain... On my side, I began to develop something like what you explain, your answer is very helpful, thanks !

Comment: I have just a little question about your f' function, when the predicate is satisfied, you put the `x :: (f' xs s d x)` between `begin ... end`, is it necessary ? And what is the meaning of `f' xs s d m in
f' l s d m` ?

Comment: Oh, the `begin ... end` isn't necessary, my bad. And about `f' xs s d m in f' l s d m`, at first glance it makes no sense. But when I write `in` I'm ending the definition of `f'` and then calling it. Something like:
`let rec f' l s d m = ... (* definition of f' *)  in
f' l s d m (* actual call *)`, so the return value is the value of the final `f'` call.

Comment: Ok, it seems clear to me now, thanks for the time you took to help me, it was very useful !

Answer (score 3):

The basic trick of functional programming is that although you can't modify the values of any variables, you can call a function with different arguments. In the initial stages of switching away from imperative ways of thinking, you can imagine making every variable you want to modify into the parameters of your function. To modify the variables, you call the function recursively with the desired new values.

This technique will work for "modifying" the variable `m`. Think of `m` as a function parameter instead.

You are already using this technique with `acc`. Each call inside the fold gets the old value of `acc` and returns the new value, which is then passed to the function again. You might imagine having both `acc` and `m` as parameters of this inner function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is useful to see how I should handle the problem.